# SVG images not showing in content blocks

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block

One of my lovely product managers has supplied me with a few *.SVG files to display in a static content block.

now if I refer to the image via a remote URL is displays fine, 
eg `scr="http://path.to.some/remote/server/file.svg"`  displays fine , however loading the file to the local server (permissions are fine I've tripple checked) and referencing similar to `scr="{{media url="wysiwyg/path/to/file/file.svg"` it does not render.

is it as simple as svg's are forbidden in magento and i need to allow? or is something more sinister happening?

Comment: which version you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the following steps to include svg images using static block.

1) upload your image on a required location for ex. `media/wysiwyg`.

2) create static block which contains this image.
for ex. [image]

3) Navigate to System->Permissions->Blocks and add your type of block.
for ex. 
[image]

4) Include your block on desired location for ex.

[image]

5) Here is the output.

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: excellent, thankyou very much, exactly what i needed (aplogies for the delay in responding, my computer dies a horrible death last week :))

Comment: great nice to here that it is useful for you.if you think this is a solution for your question then you can accept and upvote it so that it will help others.

Comment: accepted, i dont have the rep to upvote yet :(

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation. I was provided with an .svg file. I uploaded it to Magento 2 Admin. I tried loading it in Chrome browser and it didn't display, but in Firefox it did display. I was informed of this post
[Chrome Not Rendering SVG Referenced via Image Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737166/chrome-not-rendering-svg-referenced-via-img-tag), and followed the advice provided by the user MintWelsh of asking the designer who provided the .svg file to open it in Adobe Illustrator and save it with Image Location set to "Embedded" instead of "Linked". I then used the modified .svg file and it loaded in both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, but it was because my production server did not support SVG. You may need to add SVG filetype to your .htaccess file.